# Как сделать клик по картинке JS после чего выведет текст на ней-же

Tags: javascript

У меня есть картинка вставлена через JS. Как мне сделать чтобы при клике на эту картинку на ней появлялся текст "Да" или "Нет" случайным образом. Использовать HTML нельзя.

```js
var image = document.createElement("img");
document.addEventListener('click',e => console.log(e.target),
    function click(){
        let no = "no";
        let yes = "yes";
    }
)

image.src = "/shar.png"
image.style.width="350px"
my_div = document.getElementById("img");
document.body.insertBefore(image, my_div);
```

Comment: `Использовать HTML нельзя.` - это с какого перепугу :)? Если серьёзно, то просто используйте псевдоэлементы CSS'а, если так нужно.

Comment: Ну вот такое вот задание. на чистом JS всё сделать. 
Ну мне надо чтобы через рандом выводило да или нет по клику.

Comment: Погодите, так на картинке должен появляться текст или просто в консоль выводится? Я вам могу подсказать как случайно число выводить, а вы уже остальное сами :). Используя `Math.random()` выводим случайное число между 0 и 1, умножаем его на 2 (чтобы в будущем при округлении могла попасться 1) и округляем используя `Math.floor`, в конечном итоге у нас случайно выводится либо 1, либо 0. Полный код выглядит так: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)`.

Comment: `document.getElementById("img"); == undefined` Вставляй то что создал `document.body.insertBefore(image, p );` Для вывода создай какой нибудь тэг например <p></p> и в него выводи результат клика..

Comment: Текст должен появляется на картинке. Появляться может даже не через рандом а просто чередованием. console.log просто вписан чтобы понять выводит ли хоть что-то в консоль при нажатии на эту картинку. Просто для понимая

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ro4m5vta/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй такой код:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
var textOnImage = "";

let i = 1;
image.addEventListener('click',e => {
    if ( i > 0 ) {
    // ^^^ проверка чтобы код работал только один раз
    i--
    console.log(e.target)
        textOnImage = (Math.random() *1).toFixed(0);
        // ^^^ рандомное число
        
            if ( textOnImage == 1 ) {
                textOnImage = "yes";
            } else {
                textOnImage = "no";
            }
        // ^^^ на основе рандомного числа генерируем да или нет
        let text = document.createElement('div')
        text.innerHTML = textOnImage;
        document.body.insertBefore(text,image);
        text.style.fontSize = "250px";
        text.style.position = "absolute";
        // ^^^ рисуем текс с абсолютной позицией и вставляем его
        }
    }
)

image.src = "/shar.png"
image.style.width = "350px"

textOnImage = document.createElement('p')
textOnImage.fontSize = "350px";
textOnImage.innerHTML = textOnImage;

document.body.appendChild(image)

// ^^^ вставляем изображение
```